# Bash Multiplying Decimal to int

Tags: bash, decimal, multiplication

I read price from user input. When i multiply the input with int like this

> T=`"$((PRICE*QTY))"|bc`; gives
>   line 272: 12.00: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".00") 
>    or .50

depending on user input. How do i multiply these two variables and get a total with 2 decimal points?

Comment: WOW! This is good! I've never seen replies this quick in any other forums no matter how active they are and mostly get "we wont do your assignment for you" replies.
This worked for me T=`echo $QTYS\* $PRICE | bc`;
Its also rounding price to 2 decimal places without scale.
For some reason just price*QTY was giving me command not found error.

Comment: One thing to remember is that bash doesn't truly have any data types except strings. Every variable comes down to a string, so it may help you to remember that. Different programs of course will treat certain strings in a special way.

Answer (score 23):

this works:

```
PRICE=1.1
QTY=21
RES=$(echo "scale=4; $PRICE*$QTY" | bc)
echo $RES
```

Comment: Could you also explain the use of `scale` here? What does `scale=4` mean.

Comment: This is what I was missing when using `bc`! `scale` sets the precision of the operation - see the "Variables" section of [this page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bc)

Answer (score 13):

```
var=$(echo "scale=2;$PRICE*$QTY" |bc)
```

You can also use awk

```
awk -vp=$PRICE -vq=$QTY 'BEGIN{printf "%.2f" ,p * q}'
```

Comment: ./menu3.sh: line 278: 12.25: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".25")

Comment: remove the `$(())` . bash doesn't do floating arithmetic. If you want to set 2 decimal places, use scale=2

Comment: You need dollar signs before each variable name.

Comment: var=$(echo "scale=2;$PRICE*$QTY" |bc) gives me

(standard_in) 2: syntax error

Comment: bc is not installed on all distributions. I upvoted this one because awk is and he supplied an awk version that is more portable to *nix systems!

Answer (score 4):

```
T="$(echo "$PRICE*$QTY" | bc)"
```

Comment: i get (standard_in) 2: syntax error
idk why. its almost the same as above

Comment: @svenus: This one works for me. I don't know why you're getting that error from `bc`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use
mul=0.8
exp=200
texp=`awk -vp=$mul -vq=$exp 'BEGIN{printf "%.2f" ,p * q}'`

Hope this is going to work.

Comment: Please edit your answer. Its right, but not properly formatted

Answer (score 1):

First, trying to do floating-point arithmetic with `bc(1)` without using the `-l` flag is bound to give you some funny answers:

```
sarnold@haig:~$ bc -q
3.5 * 3.5
12.2
sarnold@haig:~$ bc -q -l
3.5 * 3.5
12.25
```

Second, the `$((...))` is an attempt to do arithmetic in your shell; neither my `bash` nor `dash` can handle floating point numbers.

If you want to do the arithmetic in your shell, note `printf(1)` as well as (probably) your shell's built-in `printf` function. If you want to do the arithmetic in bc, note the special variable `scale`.

Comment: most of the $(( )) with bc i tried gave me errors. Must be because of the (( ))? Thanks for the clarification.