# bash script using decimal number in arithmetic operation

Tags: bash

Suppose I have the following code

```
for n in {50..300};
do
(( a = 0.3*$n))
#do something
echo $n
echo $a
done
```

when I run the code, I received an error, it says
`((: a = 0.3*50: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".3*50")`
I know it must be  because 0.3 or any decimal number isn't recognizable or perhaps due to some formatting issues, as I previously tried `((a = $n / 2))` which worked fine, much appreciated if anyone can give me a hint.

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279932/bash-multiplying-decimal-to-int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this is quite a trivial syntax issue, using [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) to debug such errors would have been much efficient. Your error line needs to be something like

```
a=$(echo "0.3*$n" | bc )        # 'echo' to print an arithmetic expression
                              # feeding it to 'bc' for the actual computation.
```

Comment: @GavyLittlewolf: See http://ss64.com/bash/expr.html for what `expr` does.

Comment: there is an error when I tried to compile, it says `a: command not found` does that mean I need to declare the variable `a`? but I thought in bash script we do not need to?

Comment: Please paste your script in shellcheck.net and fix the errors seen, thereby making an attempt for yourself.

Comment: `expr` is the wrong command here; if `bash` could do floating-point arithmetic, you wouldn't need `bc` in the first place. It would *seem* to work since you didn't quote the argument; the expansion of `0.3*$n` didn't match any files (`*` makes it a glob pattern), so was passed literally to `expr`, which treated it as a single non-numeric argument and simply spit it back out. I've edited the answer to use `echo` to simply feed a valid expression to `bc`.

Comment: It's also not a syntax issue; `(( a = 5*$n ))` would work fine as long as `$n` expands to an integer expression.

Comment: @chepner: totally in agreement with you. The reason I wanted to use `expr` with double-quotes was to do as minimal changes from the user's incorrect attempt and make it work. Didn't want to totally revert the syntax adopted.

Comment: `expr` is completely different from the original, which again was not *syntactically* incorrect; it just fails with floating-point values.